# Subtracting from a CASE result

Tags: sql-server

I have the following CASE statement that returns the `Closure Date` column and want to subtract the `Created On` from the `Closure Date` column to get the number of days difference. I can do this with `DATEDIFF` but unsure how to make it it's own column using the existing CASE argument. I've tried a second CASE statement, even using a subquery, to no avail.

```
SELECT
    createdon [Created On],
    modifiedon [Modified On],
    timestamp [Time Stamp],
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,0, [Created On]) = DATEDIFF(minute,0,[Modified On]) THEN [Modified On]
        ELSE [Time Stamp]
    END AS 'Closure Date',
    FROM
        Table;
```

Current results:

| Created On | Closure Date |
| --- | --- |
| 7/14/23 21:23 | 7/14/23 13:45 |
| 7/14/23 21:12 | 7/14/23 12:45 |
| 7/14/23 21:11 | 7/14/23 12:49 |

What I am looking for:

| Created On | Closure Date | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/13/23 21:27 | 7/14/23 21:48 | 1.014618 |
| 7/14/23 9:24 | 7/14/23 21:45 | 0.514421 |
| 7/14/23 13:53 | 7/14/23 21:45 | 0.327616 |

Comment: You have to repeat the whole expression (not statement) or wrap in up in a cte/derived table/cross apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current comparison in the `case when` checks whether created and modified is within the same minute. If created = 13:30:59 and modified = 13:31:01 then your comparison will result in FALSE. Is this the behavior you expect?

About your question:
I didn't validate it, but this should solve your problem.

```
Select 
[Created On]
, Case
    When DATEDIFF(minute,0, [Created On]) = DATEDIFF(minute,0,[Modified On])
    Then [Modified On]
    Else [Time Stamp]
End as [Closure Date]
, Case
    When DATEDIFF(minute,0, [Created On]) = DATEDIFF(minute,0,[Modified On])
    Then Cast([Modified On] - [Created On] as float)
    Else Cast([Time Stamp] - [Created On] as float)
End as [Days]
From Table
```

Please note, that I used floats, which can be imprecise.
When you need exact numbers please read about decimales.